# Closure of subset of affine plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364962/ideal-of-polynomials-vanishing-on-x-y-x2y2-1-x-neq-0), I wonder if one can prove the following

> Let $ k $ be an algebraically closed field. Is the closure of $ \{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}=1,x\ne 0\} $ in the affine plane over $ k $ equal to $ V(x^{2}+y^{2}-1) $?

The answers to the original question use analytical methods. This is why I'm curious whether one can prove the statement above using algebraic methods.

Answer (score 0):

$\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1,x \neq 0\}=V(x^2+y^2-1) \cap \{(x,y): x \neq 0\}$ now take closure of the both sides, and observe that $\{(x,y) : x \neq 0\}$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience of notation let $A:=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1,x\neq 0\}$, $B:=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1, x=0\}$ so that $A\cup B = V(x^2+y^2-1)$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. This implies $A=B^c$ when considered as subsets in the induced topology on $V(x^2+y^2-1)$.

Notice that, for any $p\in B$ we have $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x=0$ so that $y^2=1$. But this means $y=\pm 1$ and $B$ is the two point set $\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$.

Now every finite set in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is defined by the union of finitely many algebraic varieties and therefore $B$ is an algebraic variety itself. As $A$ is it's complement we have that $A$ is open. Since $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ is irreducible, and $A\subset V(x^2+y^2-1)$ a nonempty open subset, we have that $A$ is dense in $V(x^2+y^2-1)$. This proves $\bar{A}=V(x^2+y^2-1)$.